# Comparing $foo is_array or $foo is false

Tags: php

I am trying to compare the following: **if the value is *not* an array or the value does *not* equal false, return.**

```
if (is_array($value) != true || $value != false) return;
```

This, and any other variation I am trying doesnt seem to work. However, when I compare these individually in their own if statements they return the correct results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In the current iteration, bool(false). The second iteration is array(1).

Comment: You are using `OR`, so if `$value` is not an array, this will always `return`.  Did you want `AND` instead?

Comment: Why will it always return? The clause is either it is an array or it is bool(false) - otherwise it returns.

Comment: `false` is not an array, therefore return.  `array(1)` is an array, and not `false` therefore return.

Comment: But the value must be either an array *or* false. Both values cannot exist together.

Comment: So, you only want to continue if the value is either an array or false?

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought I'd wrote above.

Comment: You got it a bit backwards.  You said: "if not an array or not false, but you really want "if not (an array or false)" :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You originally said "if it's not an array or not false".  You're thinking backwards.  You want "if the value is an array or false continue, else return".

So:

```
// This says: "if it's not (an array or false)"
if(!(is_array($value) || $value === FALSE)) return;
```

Using [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), we can convert this to

```
// This says: "if it's not an array and not false"
if(!is_array($value) && $value !== FALSE) return;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
if (!is_array($value) || $value !== false)
```

Many things in php can be == false, but only boolean false can be === false.
Check out [boolean type manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) and [comparison operators manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)